# Get String does not return value from the other class

Tags: java, android

So I have 4 classes

1. PrefUtil - Shared Preference to set and get data

```
public class PrefUtil {
    private static final String TAG = "PrefUtil";
    private SharedPreferences mSettings;

    PrefUtil(SharedPreferences prefs) {
        this.mSettings = prefs;
    }

    public String get_string(String key) {
        try {
            String value = this.mSettings.getString(key, null);
            Log.d(TAG, String.format("get_string: %s='%s'", new Object[]{key, value}));
            return value;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, String.format("get_string %s class cast exception", new Object[]{key}));
            return "";
        }
    }

    public void set_string(String key, String value) {
        Editor editor = this.mSettings.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("set_string: %s='%s'", new Object[]{key, value}));
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

2. OpenVPNService - uses PrefUtil to set data

```
private PrefUtil prefs;
prefs.set_string("payload", pl);
prefs.set_string("proxyhost", pr);
prefs.set_string("proxyport", String.valueOf(pport));
```

3. HTTPSupport - to get or fetch data

```
public class HTTPSupport
{
    private Socket incoming;
    private String netDataString;
    private String[] bugHostRotate;
    private String[] bugHostRotate2;
    private String[] bugHostRotate3;
    private int countRotate = 0;
    private int countRotate2 = 0;
    private int countRotate3 = 0;
    private Random mRandom = new Random();
    private int k = 0;
    private int h = 0;
    private int i = 0;
    private Context mContext;
    private Socket mSocket;
    private PrinceUtil util;
    
    public HTTPSupport(Socket in){
        incoming = in;
    }

    public HTTPSupport(Context c){
        mContext = c;
    }
    
    public Socket socket() {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, util.getPayload(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        String trim;
        Socket socket = null;
        String remote = util.getProxyHost() + ":" + util.getProxyPort();
        }
}
```

4. PrinceUtil - class to get data

```
public class PrinceUtil {
    private PrefUtil prefs;
    
    public String getPayload() {
        return prefs.get_string("payload");
    }
    
    public String getProxyHost() {
        return prefs.get_string("proxyhost");
    }
    
    public String getProxyPort() {
        return prefs.get_string("proxyport");
    }
}
```

The problem is that set string works it returns data when I debug it or toast it to MainActivity but in HTTPSupport when I call util.getProxyHost() it is null it doesn't return data. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing in PrinceUtil assigns to prefs

Comment: The set string has been done in OpenVPNService or can you elaborate or arrange the code on how to? Thanks

Comment: how does HTTPSupport get its instance of the Util class?
My first guess is that the instance you set the data and the instance that you retrieve the data from are different.

Comment: In HTTPSupport I use
private PrinceUtil util;
util.getProxyHost();

is this correct?

Comment: The field `PrinceUtil#prefs` is never assigned. It will always be `null` and all methods will throw a `NullPointerException` when trying to invoke methods on it. Same for `HTTPSupport#util`, it is never assigned a value

Answer (score 1):

In the `PrinceUtil` class, the `prefs` field is never assigned. In Java, the default value of a reference type field is `null`, so attempts to call any methods on `prefs` will throw a `NullPointerException`. You can correct this by adding a constructor that allows an instance of `PrefUtil` to be supplied when creating an instance of `PrinceUtil`:

```
public PrinceUtil(PrefUtil prefs) {
    this.prefs = prefs;
}
```

Note that this is similar to how `PrefUtil` has a constructor that accepts a `SharedPreferences` instance.

You'll also need to do the same for the `util` field in `HTTPSupport`. The current code includes two constructors in that class, one that sets `incoming`, and one that sets `mContext`. This means that in any instance of `HTTPSupport`, one of these fields will be unset, and `util` will always be unset. I would recommend combining these into one constructor that takes all three values:

```
public HTTPSupport(Socket incoming, Context mContext, PrinceUtil util){
    this.incoming = incoming;
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.util = util;
}
```

There are other unset fields in the source code provided, but they're also not used in any of the methods. I'm assuming that the code is incomplete, but these also need to be initialized before use.